# alternative to {% if request.user.is_active %} in Django Templates

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-templates, render-to-response

What are the logic alternatives about:

```
{% if request.user.is_active %}
```

If the view doesn't return `render_to_response` with a dictionary with `request`, the template doesn't works properly.

So, any ideas are welcome.

//edited

my motivation is: when you work with views from installed apps, that you don't have the opportunity to modify them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in your `settings.py`.

Now your have `user` variable in all your templates. So you can use this:

```
{% if user.is_active %}
```

See more in the docs: [template context processors in settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS), [auth context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth).

Comment: `auth` is included by default, also could use `request` context processor which is not included by default. Furthermore, its better to note that `RequestContext` is required for the usage.

Answer (score 5):

view.py:

```
def foo_view(request):
    ...
    is_active = request.user.is_active
    return render_to_response('template.html', {'is_active':is_active})
```

or context_processor:

```
def is_user_active(request):
    return {'is_active': request.user.is_active}
```

or middleware:

```
class IsUserActive:
    def process_template_response(self, request, response):
        response.context['is_active'] = request.user.is_active
```

---

template.html:

```
{% if is_active %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

But sincerely, I don't know why render_to_response does not satisfy you:

```
...
return render_to_response('template.html', 
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: when you use some views from installed apps that you could not modify.for example: userena app, signin, signout views.